# Unable to send APN notifications with pyapns

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns/ to send notifications to our iPhone application.

I have tested sending a notification manually and have confirmed that we can do so successfully. We are looking for a robust solution and have heard great things about pyapns. However this is the log output we see in twistd.log and we never receive the notification.

The key differences are:

1. We are using pyapns
2. We are using a different cert -- specifically, when we manually send the notification we provide both the key and the cert -- and then provide the password to authenticate reading the cert. For pyapns, we create a combined cert + key with the password removed. But we still are unable to receive the notification.

I'm unsure what the root cause is -- if there is an issue with the cert or why we are failing to send the notification.

Here are logs from twistd.log:

```
2012-04-04 01:21:51+0000 [-] Log opened.
2012-04-04 01:21:51+0000 [-] twistd 12.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.2) starting up.
2012-04-04 01:21:51+0000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2012-04-04 01:21:51+0000 [-] Site starting on 7077
2012-04-04 01:21:51+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x1f2a908>
2012-04-04 01:31:57+0000 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] APNSService __init__
2012-04-04 01:31:57+0000 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2012:01:31:57 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 114 "-" "xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)"
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [HTTPChannel,1,127.0.0.1] APNSService write (connecting)
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [HTTPChannel,1,127.0.0.1] APNSClientContextFactory ssl_cert_file={FROM_STRING}
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [HTTPChannel,1,127.0.0.1] Starting factory <pyapns.server.APNSClientFactory instance at 0x2065b48>
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [HTTPChannel,1,127.0.0.1] APNSClientFactory startedConnecting
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [Uninitialized] APNSProtocol connectionMade
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [Uninitialized] APNSProtocol sendMessage msg=00002079d7b66de69c6f5e78e5eef9d37d5c69b7b6e7adbdeba75ef5af5ce3b737dde7001a7b22617073223a7b22616c657274223a
2248656c6c6f21227d7d
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [Uninitialized] 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2012:01:34:31 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 114 "-" "xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)"
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] APNSProtocol connectionLost
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] APNSClientFactory clientConnectionLost reason=[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <clas
s 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
    ]
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x2065c68> will retry in 2 seconds
2012-04-04 01:34:32+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] Stopping factory <pyapns.server.APNSClientFactory instance at 0x2065b48>
2012-04-04 01:34:35+0000 [-] Starting factory <pyapns.server.APNSClientFactory instance at 0x2065b48>
2012-04-04 01:34:35+0000 [-] APNSClientFactory startedConnecting
2012-04-04 01:34:35+0000 [Uninitialized] APNSProtocol connectionMade
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [HTTPChannel,2,127.0.0.1] APNSService read (connecting)
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [HTTPChannel,2,127.0.0.1] APNSClientContextFactory ssl_cert_file={FROM_STRING}
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [HTTPChannel,2,127.0.0.1] Starting factory <pyapns.server.APNSFeedbackClientFactory instance at 0x206ccb0>
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [HTTPChannel,2,127.0.0.1] APNSFeedbackClientFactory startedConnecting
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [Uninitialized] feedbackHandler connectionMade
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [APNSFeedbackHandler (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] feedbackHandler connectionLost [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twist
ed.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
    ]
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [APNSFeedbackHandler (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2012:01:34:53 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 138 "-" "xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by ww
w.pythonware.com)"
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [APNSFeedbackHandler (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] APNSFeedbackClientFactory clientConnectionLost reason=[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no
 frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
    ]
2012-04-04 01:34:53+0000 [APNSFeedbackHandler (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] Stopping factory <pyapns.server.APNSFeedbackClientFactory instance at 0x206ccb0>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm able to send notifications, but these logs keep on generating